# symfony2 form disable

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, subforms

I am using the same form to "preview" an object as I am to "edit/update" the same object.
In my `showAction()` for the controller I have the following code:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new SalesEntityType($entity), $entity, array('read_only' => true) );
```

This code works great for the primary form but there are a number of subforms that are made part of this by inclusion.  One example in the show.html.twig is:

```
{% include 'TargetCommonBundle:Hours:hoursForm.html.twig' with { form: hours } %}
```

Unfortunately, the read_only setting on the parent form does not seem to cascade to the included subforms.  Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: It seems that the read_only works fine in the subforms as it does in the main form.  It is just that the none of the drop-down lists in the main or subforms are disabled from being changed.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the read_only variable to the with statement? ie: with { form: hours, read_only: read_only }

Comment: Try: $form = $this->createForm(new SalesEntityType($entity), $entity, array('disabled' => true) );

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

> ```
> $form = $this->createForm(
>     new SalesEntityType($entity),
>     $entity,
>     [ 'disabled' => true ]
> );
> ```

See: vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/CHANGELOG.md, first line

Answer (score 3):

```
// It is the way more fast to disabled a form
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->setDisabled(true);
}
```